# How to display 2 No Results Found text when search result is not found? In Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have 2 `TextViews` and 2 `ListViews` and an `EditText` in my main xml file.

The "Search" `EditText` is first, 
then "Tools" `TextView`, 
then "Tools" `ListView`, 
then "Articles" `TextView`, 
then "Articles" `ListView`.

What I wanted to do is display `"No Results Found for Tools"` when someone type in a word (i.e "test") and it does not exists in my sql, I want to display this in my tools section and `"No Results found for Articles"` in my articles section

My main problem is, when I run the project, it has a huge space between the textViews.
It looks like this

```
No Results Found in Tools




No Results Found in Articles.
```

The output that I want to achieve is:

```
No Results Found in Tools

No Results Found in Articles
```

I tried setting the visibility of the listview to gone but still doesn't work. Can you help me?

EDIT: here is my xml layout for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_search"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/violet"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_search"
            android:paddingLeft="35dp" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextSearch"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textArticlesResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="@string/label_articles"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewArticlesResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textArticlesResult"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textToolsResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/label_tools"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            android:layout_below = "@id/listViewArticlesResult" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listViewToolsResult"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textToolsResult"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabHome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_home_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabFb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_fb_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_search_selected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabFaves"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_myfaves_unselected" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabSettings"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_settings_unselected" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Code/XML would help (depending on how those search results are shown), and I wouldn't say that this is an Eclipse problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chunck of Your code:`

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textArticlesResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/label_articles"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewArticlesResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textArticlesResult"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

replace to:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textArticlesResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/label_articles"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewArticlesResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/white"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:visibility="visible" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and modify `android:visibility` of `RelativeLayout` which encapsulates your `ListView`